# How do I promisify my S3 getObjectUrl function?

Tags: javascript, express, promise

I am having a hard time with promises, how would I promisify my function below?

I want to do something like s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrl().promise() to get a promise for each operation then use Promise.all(...) to wait on the result of all operations before responding???

```
router.get(`/api/verification/load`, auth, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ GETS A USER })

    let urlArray = []

    const keyArray = [user.idKey, user.selfieKey]
   
    for (const key in keyArray) {
      s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrl(
        "getObject",
        {
          Bucket: "app-verification",
          Key: key,
          Expires: 30,
        },
        (err, url) => urlArray.push(url)
      )
    }

    if (urlArray.length === 0) {  
      console.log("URL ARRAY EMPTY")  -> RETURNS "URL ARRAY EMPTY"
    }

    const idUrl = urlArray[0]
    const selfieUrl = urlArray[1]

    res.send({ user, idUrl, selfieUrl })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const urlArray = await Promise.all(keyArray.map(key =>
    s3VerificationBucket.getSignedUrlPromise(
        "getObject",
        {
            Bucket: "app-verification",
            Key: key,
            Expires: 30,
        }
    )
));
```

See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property) for documentation about `getSignedUrlPromise`